# Weighting observations in a spdep::lagsarlm Model?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, r-sp, spdep

I would like to estimate a `spdep::lagsarlm` Model (Spatially Autoregressive Regression) in R. My observations (n=447) are polygons, each representing an administrative region of Berlin.

However, the problem is that the regions have a highly varying number of inhabitants (between 500 and 32000). Therefore, I would like to weight each observation with its number of inhabitants. With `lm` this is easypeasy, because it accepts the optional argument `weights=`...

How can I do something similar with `spdep::lagsarlm`? Is there a workaround?

Comment: What happened to your answer? I thought it was a good addition.

Comment: Maybe think heteroscastic errors, and look at package `sphet` and the two corresponding JSS papers?

Comment: @LyzandeR: I deleted it because the author did not give me permission to post it on Stack.

Comment: @Gui_struggling_with_R That's a pity... I am sure it might help someone. Anyway, it's his choice.. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: According to Roger Bivand, this has not been developed yet (as of 2015). See his response here. http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Weighting-observations-in-a-spdep-lagsarlm-Model-td7587871.html

Answer (score 4):

I haven't used `spdep::lagsarlm` but it is very easy to replicate the way `lm` uses weights using the following method:

Let's assume you have a data.frame `df` defined as:

```
df <- data.frame(a=runif(10), b=runif(10))

> df
           a          b
1  0.8266429 0.43591733
2  0.4624063 0.93180891
3  0.7085656 0.36468984
4  0.3339251 0.79093356
5  0.8236406 0.39687242
6  0.8266429 0.83213817
7  0.4624063 0.34714824
8  0.7085656 0.01812133
9  0.3339251 0.54498829
10 0.8236406 0.73677156
```

and a weights vector defined as:

```
c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
```

Running an `lm` on the above data produces the following results:

```
> lm(a~b, data=df, weights=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2))

Call:
lm(formula = a ~ b, data = df, weights = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 2, 2))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            b  
     0.6672      -0.0467
```

Let's see now how the function `lm` actually uses the weights vector.

We start by replicating the rows of the data.frame df by the number defined in the weights like this:

```
replicate_rows <- rep(1:nrow(df), c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2))
```

Rows with a weight of 2 appear twice as you can see below:

```
> replicate_rows
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  5  6  6  7  7  8  8  9  9 10 10
```

Use the above to make a new data.frame `df2` that uses those rows:

```
df2 <- df[replicate_rows, ]

> df2
             a          b
1    0.8266429 0.43591733
2    0.4624063 0.93180891
3    0.7085656 0.36468984
4    0.3339251 0.79093356
5    0.8236406 0.39687242
5.1  0.8236406 0.39687242
6    0.8266429 0.83213817
6.1  0.8266429 0.83213817
7    0.4624063 0.34714824
7.1  0.4624063 0.34714824
8    0.7085656 0.01812133
8.1  0.7085656 0.01812133
9    0.3339251 0.54498829
9.1  0.3339251 0.54498829
10   0.8236406 0.73677156
10.1 0.8236406 0.73677156
```

I have replicated the rows of the dataframe df according to the weights. Let's run an `lm` now without the use of weights:

```
> lm(a~b, data=df2)

Call:
lm(formula = a ~ b, data = df2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            b  
     0.6672      -0.0467
```

As you can see the results are exactly the same!

You can use the above to weigh your data.frame accordingly and then use it in your `spdep::lagsarlm` function.

Comment: Do you have any paper backing this up (or am I doomed to go through the literature cited in `?lm`?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik No I don't have any paper backing this up unfortunately. The literature in `lm` doesn't specify anything else either. But this is the way the weights argument is used in `lm` as shown above.

Comment: It makes sense, in an intuitive way, just like outlayers have "weights" to them, the same way you can put some influence on existing data points by duplicating/triplicating... them. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik -- There's also a sentence to that effect in `?lm`, which might give you even more confidence that that's what `weights` is about. Here's a snippet from it: "'weights' can be used to indicate, [when the elements of 'weights' are positive integers  w_i], that each response y_i is the mean of w_i unit-weight observations (including the case that there are w_i observations equal to y_i and the data have been summarized)". Pretty nifty, isn't it?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks for the comment. That makes it clearer. I ll update if I find anything else as well. I remember reading about it somewhere too (not in a paper though).

Comment: In `lm` it shouldn't because that is how the weights are implemented anyway. I haven't used `spdep::lagsarlm` but it shouldn't affect them in a negative way since you only alter the number of rows according to the weights. And thanks :)

Comment: What works for basic linear regression shouldn't be expected to necessarily work here. I would imagine that creating duplicates of rows (or locations in this case) would screw up the matrix of weights that the SAR regression creates.